# Papers2 incompatiblity with Word 2011 on Mac OS X?

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2011, citations

I'm using Papers2 with Word 2011 to insert citations (citation magic) into a Word document. I'm using Mac OS X 10.6.8. I recently updated my Papers2 and since then, I'm unable to insert my bibliography into Word documents that previously worked fine. Any idea how to get around this?

I considered installing Papers3, but that requires a new version of Mac OS X, which I cannot upgrade to since my Mac laptop is older.  Is there a way to fix this or to somehow get rid of the new update (downgrade) in Papers2 so that I can restore magic citations capabilities in Word?

thanks.